# An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details

Tags: eclipse

```
 ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred while installing the items
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:291)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:551)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:899)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3851)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3779)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3760)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3638)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1343)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$33(SimpleVariablePage.java:1211)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1156)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Tawiah_java-2021-033_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64 4.19.0.20210311-1200, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.UnzipAction).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives code=0 The artifact for binary,epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64,4.19.0.20210311-1200 is not available.
```

Comment: That seems to come from the Eclipse Installer, right? Make sure the Eclipse Installer is up to date. If retrying does not help, [download a IDE package directly](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, downloading a IDE package directly is a problem resolution.
macOS 10.14.6

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30450533)